# what is expansion joint(compensating tube) in pressure vessels?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I've seen it in the drawing,the expansion joint holds the nozzle.so why the expansion joint looks like this picture.what is the necessity of shaping the tube like this.in this picture the nozzle passes through the expansion joint has a diameter 57 mm.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The expansion joint is designed and fitted to compensate or protect the equipment from changes in dimension due to changes in temperature and / or pressure.